# How to take print out of WPF window stackpanel

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF Windows application. In one window there is a particular stackpanel which is holding some user data.

I want to take print out this stackpanel only.

Pls suggest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `StackPanel` is called "ui_stackPanel", and you have a button named "ui_print" with a corresponding click event:

```
    private void ui_print_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
        if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            printDialog.PrintVisual(ui_stackPanel, "Stack panel description");
        }
    }
```

There is a lot more to printing than this, this will simply print the visual as it looks on your screen. But this should get you started.